# Twitter Bootstrap 3 Search Box not Displaying Correctly

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, search-box

I am using bootstrap v3.3.5 and VS 2015 framework 4.6 my default web application project. I am trying to get the search box to display with rounded edges on the navigation bar and the placeholder text to display. What I am getting is straight edges, no placeholder text, no glyphicon image, and the button showing on the row below it. Below is my asp.net markup code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>

    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

    <script src="Scripts/WebForms/MSAjax/MicrosoftAjax.js" language="JavaScript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" language="JavaScript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js" language="JavaScript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/respond.js" language="JavaScript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" language="JavaScript"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <!--<form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
            <Scripts>


    <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
                <%--Site Scripts--%>
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>-->

        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">


 <div class="container">

                    <a class="" href="~/">
                        <img class="" src="Images/openrecordslogo.jpg" />
                    </a>


                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="~/" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Home<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Appeal Form</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        <li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="~/" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Advanced Search<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        <li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="~/" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Reports Generation<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        <li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="~/" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Other Applications<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">RTKL Application</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        <li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="~/" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Resources<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Resource 1</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        <li>
                        <li>
                    </ul>
                    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="container body-content">


    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <hr />
    <footer>
    <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - My ASP.NET Application</p>
    </footer>

    </div>

    <!--</form>-->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using localhost in compatibility mode.